# In a topological space if there exists a loop that cannot be contracted to a point does there exist a simple loop that cannot be contracted also?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm interested in whether one only needs to consider simple loops when proving results about simply connected spaces.

If it is true that:

**In a Topological Space, if there exists a loop that cannot be contracted to a point then there exists a simple loop that cannot also be contracted to a point.**

then we can replace a loop by a simple loop in the definition of simply connected.

If this theorem is not true for all spaces, then perhaps it is true for Hausdorff spaces or metric spaces or a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I have thought about the simplest non-trivial case which I believe would be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In this case I have a  quite elementary way to approach this which is to see that you can contract a loop by shrinking its simple loops.

Take any loop, a continuous map, $f$,  from $[0,1]$. Go round the loop from 0 until you find a self intersection at $x \in (0,1]$ say, with the previous loop arc, $f([0,x])$ at a point $f(y)$ where $0<y<x$. Then $L=f([y,x])$ is a simple loop. Contract $L$ to a point and then apply the same process to $(x,1]$, iterating until we reach $f(1)$. At each stage we contract a simple loop. Eventually after a countably infinite number of contractions we have contracted the entire loop. We can construct a single homotopy out of these homotopies by making them maps on $[1/2^i,1/2^{i+1}]$ consecutively which allows one to fit them all into the unit interval.

So if you can't contract a given non-simple loop to a point but can contract any simple loop we have a contradiction which I think proves my claim.

I'm not sure whether this same argument applied to more general spaces or whether it is in fact correct at all. I realise that non-simple loops can be phenomenally complex with highly non-smooth, fractal structure but I can't see an obvious reason why you can't do what I propose above.

**Update: Just added another question related to this about classifying the spaces where this might hold - [In which topological spaces does the existence of a loop not contractible to a point imply there is a non-contractible simple loop also?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338070/in-which-topological-spaces-does-the-existence-of-a-loop-not-contractable-to-a-p)**

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Here is an example of topological space $X$, embeddable as compact subspace of $\mathbf{R}^3$, that is not simply connected, but in which every simple loop is homotopic to a constant loop.

Namely, start from the Hawaiian earring $H$, with its singular point $w$. Let $C$ be the cone over $H$, namely $C=H\times [0,1]/H\times\{0\}$. Let $w$ be the image of $(w,1)$ in $C$. Finally, $X$ is the bouquet of two copies of $(C,w)$; this is a path-connected, locally path-connected, compact space, embeddable into $\mathbf{R}^3$.

[image]

It is classical that $X$ is not simply connected: this is an example of failure of a too naive version of van Kampen's theorem.

However every simple loop in $X$ is homotopic to a constant loop. Indeed, since the joining point $w\in X$ separates $X\smallsetminus\{w\}$ into two components, such a loop cannot pass through $w$ and hence is included in one of these two components, hence one of the two copies of the cone $C$, in which it can clearly be homotoped to the sharp point of the cone.

Comment: Thanks Anton Petrunin for the picture!

Comment: Thank you for this excellent example. I have a question which is that I can see why any simple loop must be on one cone and can then be contracted, but why can't non-simple loops that presumably must pass through w have their loops dropped down and passed over their respective cone points and then moved back up to w (I'm assuming w is the point where all the circles meet) and hence contract to a point.

Comment: Roughly, let $a_n$ be the $n$-th loop based at $w$ in the first copy of $H$ and $b_n$ the one in the second copy. Then the "infinite product" $\prod_n a_nb_n$ is not homotopic to a constant loop.

Comment: By n-th loop do you mean a loop around the n-th circle so $a_nb_n$ is a figure of eight passing through w and the product is a bunch of these attached at w. (Apologies if these are basic questions)

Comment: Yes, the product is the (non-commutative) infinite concatenation $a_1b_1a_2b_2\dots$. (I don't call it a bunch, since a loop is a map and not just a space).

Comment: Thank you again for your clarification. In trying to understand why my simple proof doesn't work in this case I have another question if that's OK? Can any $a_n$ or $b_n$ be contracted to w? (It seems intuitively that they can by sliding the loop down and around the respective cone's apex and back up to w). If they all can be then can't we just construct a homotopy out of these that contracts the entire infinite product to w? (If they can't then can we construct a counterexample out of two circles rather than an infinite number?)

Comment: Yes, each $a_n$ and each $b_n$ (and each finite product of these) is homotopic to a constant loop. A word is needed on this infinite loop: it is indexed by $[0,1]$, say $a_1$ indexed by $[0,1/2]$, $b_1$ by $[1/2,3/4]$, $a_2$ by $[3/4,7/8]$, etc. That it is well defined relies on the fact that $a_n$ and $b_n$ tend to $w$ uniformly. But if you concatenate homotopies, the concatenation is not continuous at time $1$.

Comment: Just to insist, the path defined as concatenation $\left(\prod_n a_n\right)\left(\prod_n b_n\right)$ is homotopic to a constant path (while it has the same support as $\prod_na_nb_n$).

Comment: PS this space is mentioned in [MathSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788471/fundamental-group-of-wedge-sum-of-two-coni-over-hawaiian-earrings); it seems that the original reference is: *H.B. Griffiths, The fundamental group of two spaces with a common point, Quart. J. Math. Oxford (2) 5 (1954) 175-190.*

Answer (score 40):

Every finite simplicial complex is weakly homotopy equivalent to a finite space. Therefore there are finite spaces with nontrivial loops; and these are obviously not embedded.

Comment: Nice non-Hausdorff examples! An explicit one (of the minimal possible cardinal) is the 4-element set $\{0,+,\infty,-\}$ with topology given by closed subsets $$\big\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{\infty\},\{0,+,\infty\},\{0,-,\infty\},\{0,+,\infty,-\} \big\}.$$ It can be view as quotient of the circle $\mathbf{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ by the action of the group of positive homotheties. Actually a lower-dimensional analogue of the question is whether there are spaces that are path-connected and not (injective path)-connected, and in this case the only examples are non-Hausdorff.

Comment: PS $\{0,\infty\}$ is missing among closed subsets in the example of my previous comment.

Comment: @YCor This 4-point space is apparently called the [pseudocircle](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocircle). (Not sure by whom?? [Barmak-Minian](//zbmath.org/?q=an:1185.55005) have it as the *minimal finite model of $S^1$*, [May](//mathoverflow.net/a/177474) as the *non-Hausdorff suspension of $S^0$*, denoted $\mathbb SS^0$.) But does it, or another like it, help answer the OP’s question?

Answer (score 15):

This question came up when I was taking a course in topology in a bygone century. For homework I constructed an example of a subspace $X$ of $\mathbb R^3$ which is not simply connected although every simple closed curve in $X$ is homotopic to a point. It was something like this:

Take an infinite sequence of circles in the $xy$-plane, each circle externally tangent to the next one, with the centers of the circles lying on a straight line and converging to the origin. For concreteness, we may suppose that the $n^\text{th}$ circle is a circle of radius $\frac1{2^n}$ centered at $\left(\frac3{2^n},0\right)$. Make each of those circles the base of a right circular cone of height $1$. Finally, let $X$ be the closure of the union of that sequence of cones. Every simple closed curve in $X$ can be shrunk to a point in $X$, since it lies on one cone; but a closed curve which goes around the bases of all the cones cannot be shrunk to a point in $X$.

[image: picture]

From the same course I **vaguely** recall a proposition to the effect that, if $X$ is "locally simply connected in the large" (meaning that each point has a neighborhood $U$ such that every closed curve in $U$ is homotopic to a point in $X$), and if every simple closed curve in $X$ is homotopic to a point, then $X$ is simply connected. I don't recall if there were other conditions on $X$ (such as "Hausdorff space" or "metric space"), and I certainly don't recall anything about the proof, except that it could not have been anything deep.

**P.S.** This example seems to be well-known folklore. It is given without attribution in F. Galvin, Covering spaces and simple connectedness, M.A. thesis, University of Minnesota, 1961.

Comment: Nice example (simpler than mine); I added a picture.

Comment: This example is homotopy equivalent to the analogous compactification of the harmonic archipelago. However, the harmonic archipelago does have a non-contractible simple closed curve. This means the property the OP is interested in is _not_ an invariant of homotopy type.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas it's quite clear that for every path-connected not simply connected $X$, the space $X\times [0,1]^2$ has an injective non-contractible path (just make a homotopically non-trivial path in the $X$-direction and an injective path in the $[0,1]^2$-direction.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for adding the picture.

Comment: @YCor Good point!

Comment: Is this path-connected?

Comment: @bof I would think it wouldn’t be for the same reason as the topologist’s sine curve.

Comment: @AviSteiner Let $A=\{(x,y,z)\in X:z=0,y\ge0\}$, $B=\{(x,y,z)\in X:z=0,y\le0\}$, $C=\{(x,y,z)\in X:z=0\}$. Now $A$ is path-connected because it's homeomorphic to the closed interval $[0,2]$ via the homeomorphism $(x,y,z)\mapsto x$; $B$ is path-connected for the same reason; $C$ is path-connected because $C=A\cup B$ and $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$; and  $X$ is path-connected because each point in $X$ is connected by a path in $X$ (a straight line segment) to a point in $C$.

Comment: See a similar example by Bill Thurston in a related post: https://mathoverflow.net/a/60855/7113

Comment: This other post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220709/existence-of-a-non-null-homotopic-simple-closed-curve also gives the same example.

Comment: @D.R. It seems to be well known folklore. An archaic source for this example is F. Galvin's M.A. thesis (U. of Minnesota, 1961).