# In which topological spaces does the existence of a loop not contractible to a point imply there is a non-contractible simple loop also?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

In another MathOverflow post I asked: [In a topological space if there exists a loop that cannot be contracted to a point does there exist a simple loop that cannot be contracted also?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337942/in-a-topological-space-if-there-exists-a-loop-that-cannot-be-contracted-to-a-poi)

Note that once consequence of this is that for spaces in which this holds you only need to consider simple loops when proving that a space is not simply connected. This also suggests that looking at path-connected spaces only would still be interesting.

Some very elegant and interesting counterexamples were given, both Hausdorff (for a space embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and non-Hausdorff.

**I propose a follow up question which is to determine the spaces with the property that if there exists a loop that cannot be contracted to a point there exists a simple loop that cannot be contracted also?.** (Or equivalent to classify the counterexamples in some way)

For example what conditions can be place on a space embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to force the condition to hold?

Update: Given that this is quite a broad question I have asked another question specifically about the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case: [In a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is not simply connected does there exist a simple-loop that contracts to a point?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338073/in-a-subset-of-mathbbr2-which-is-not-simply-connected-does-there-exist-a-s)

Answer (score -2):

Some very sketchy and preliminary thoughts of my own that I didn't want to place in the question to reduce clutter:

I believe that this property does hold unconditionally for any subset of the plane, $\mathbb{R}^2$. I gave an elementary argument for this in the previous post which may not be correct but I think is plausible.  (A slick proof of this or counterexample would be great).

Based on the $\mathbb{R}^3$ counterexample which consisted of two connected spaces joined at a single point I venture the highly speculative guess guess that for any space embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the condition does hold if the space cannot be separated by the removal of a finite number of points. I have no proof for this but I think that my speculative proof for $\mathbb{R}^2$ may work for these cases as without such points you can't force simple loops to stay in simply connected components if a space is composed of these joined at single points which is necessary condition possibly for any counterexample.

Comment: I think your "proof" in the planar case is too naive ("the first self-intersection" is not well-defined), and that the case of subsets of the plane would deserve a separate question (which I can't solve).

Comment: What if the space embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ was path-connected would that help?

Comment: No since the question obviously boils down to the path-connected case.

Comment: I will probably ask the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case as a separate question and link to here.

Comment: Just on the point you raised about my "proof": I actually define the first intersection by "Go round the loop from 0 until you find a self intersection at x∈(0,1] say, with the previous loop arc" so I am only considering the curve intersecting with a point of the curve that has already "happened" i.e has smaller inverse image in [0,1]. Isn't this well-defined?

Comment: This might accumulate at $x=0$.

Comment: Does this mean that the curve "stops" at 0 so f(x)=0 for all $x\in [0,\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon>0$? In which case can't we just identify those curve points and this won't affect the contractibility of the loop? (Apologies if this is a naive question)

Comment: Have in mind a Peano curve. There exists $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ that is injective on no nonempty open interval (and such that the image of any nonempty open interval has nonempty interior).